# How do I go about fixing this old photograph?

Tags: photoshop, exposure, photo-editing, restoration

I was wondering how you would go about fixing this photograph?
How would you describe what was wrong with it, over/under exposed?

[Problem Photo http://www.varstudios.com/img100_01.jpg](http://www.varstudios.com/img100_01.jpg)

It's an old scanned image, i have a few in the same condition and i was hoping to fix them up a bit.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is some haze in the picture. 
The steps I would follow are these:

- Photoshop CC 2015 has a dehaze function that could remove it.
- Then I would correct the color balance and remove some magenta and some Yellow.
- Increase saturation
- boost blacks and whites a little bit.

you can do all this also using the latest version of Lightroom, (also has the new dehaze function) or by using free software like gimp. Dont know how that works tough.

EDIT:
here is a **quick and dirty sample** edit to demonstrate the above steps (except dehaze functionality that has been done manually since I am not on the latest version yet.)

[image: Sample edit]

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately like yourself i don't have Photoshop CC 2015, but i will have a go at the other pieces of advice you have given.

Comment: Ok, you can do it manually by boosting the blacks and lowering the whites and playing with contrast! Good luck

Comment: also please consider marking one of the answers as accepted if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have the original negatives available? These will have more detail than the scans of prints, and can be rescanned at much higher bitdepth, possibly allowing you to edit them more completely.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I would describe with it is "color cast", likely caused by the slide that was scanned.  There are many ways to try and remove color cast.  I usually use Nik Color Efex 4, but I am sure there are some free options out there as well.

If you have photoshop, this is a good tutorial: https://fstoppers.com/studio/check-out-brilliant-way-remove-color-casts-photoshop-8036

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i looked at the tutorial, but my picture are much worse than that in the tut.